# Regular Expressions truncate rather than choose C#

Tags: c#, regex, truncate, cut

I tried dozens of codes and used some from regexlib but the following code truncates data rather than choose a correct one

```
string pattern = @"(\d{1,3}(\,\d{3})*|(\d+))(\.\d{2})";
string input = "The numbers are 340.1 1,989.50 2,8000,100.50 3.5000 15.001 15.1";
MatchCollection collection = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
foreach (Match m in collection)
{
Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

The results are:

- 1,989.50 - this is OK
- 000,100.50 - this is not OK. It cut first digit from 2,8000,100.50, and took it
- 3.50 - this is not OK. It cut 2 last digits from 3.5000 and took it
- 15.00 - this is not OK. It cut 1 last digit, truncate data and took it
- 15.1 is not in the list. This is OK

I would like to match only digits this type: 1.00 100.00 1,000.00 100,000.00. All the rest should be neglected. At the moment x.000 are also taken and truncated 
Thank you!

ADDED
I managed to stop using 3.5000 and 15.001 by adding space. But still can't deal with **2,8000,100.50**

```
(\d{1,3}(\,\d{3})*|(\d+))(\.\d{2} )
```

Comment: `\,\d{3}` 8000 has 4  digits?!

Comment: you might want to add the expected result to the ones that are not okay.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and tell us what the expected result should be?

Comment: Why not simply try to parse the number with `double.TryParse()`?

Comment: Hello. I would like to match only digits this type: 1.00 100.00 1,000.00 100,000.00. All the rest should be neglected. At the moment x.000 are also taken and truncated

Answer (score 0):

Regex:

```
(?<=^|\s)\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{2})(?=\s|$)
```

[Updated Demo](https://regex101.com/r/KQGKwl/3)

Comment: Unfortunately this code matches all numbers and I need only 1,989.50 from my input

Comment: I have updated the regex based on the new edit to the question

Comment: It works great in regex101, but in C# it doesn't match anything. Previously I tried ^ and $ and it never worked as it seaches for the first and the last word of an input

Comment: Sorry, it worked great when I put the code once again! Thank you!